# ExpandableListview with Childitems as Images (in tile format like gallery) in android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Can any one suggest me how to create an Expandable Listview with ChildItem as Images in Tile format. i.e When I click on the main Item it will expand and show me the respective images as tiles below that. I have tried achieving this referring some example code from GitHub '`ExpandableListview`', '`CollapseListView`'.
Have tried it with `customrenderer ListView` in android platform in which the MainView.axml contains a `Textview` and the ChildView.axml contains GridView in which I will populate images. But in this scenario whenever the Expandable item in the `MainView` is clicked the `Gridview` with all the images are repeated with all its images.
I need only one `GridView` with all my images populated under the main Item when It is clicked. I am using xamarin.forms portable project.
Please anyone help me in this.

These are my DataAdpater.cs. In its `GetsChildView` I am Binding the `Gridview` but the `Gridview` is binded repeatedly whatever the no. of `childitems` it has. How can I avoid that

```
public class DataAdapter: BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    readonly Activity Context;
    public int cnt = 0;
    public DataAdapter(Activity newContext, List<HomeOwner> newList) : base()
    {
        Context = newContext;
        DataList = newList;
    }

    protected List<HomeOwner> DataList { get; set; }

    public override Android.Views.View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View header = convertView;
        if (header == null)
        {
            header = Context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.NativeListView, null);
        }
        header.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtView).Text = DataList[groupPosition].Category;
       // header.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridview).Adapter = new ImageAdapter(Context, DataList[groupPosition].CategoryList);
        return header;
    }

    public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        ImageView imageView;

        if (row == null)
        {
            row = Context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ChildCell, null);
            imageView = new ImageView(Context);
            imageView.LayoutParameters = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(85, 85);
            imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
            imageView.SetPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        else
        {
             imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }
         List <category> newValue = new List<category>();
         GetChildViewHelper(groupPosition, out newValue);
        //getAdapter(row.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridview));
       // row.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridview).Adapter = new ImageAdapter(Context, newValue);
        //row.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.txtTitle).SetImageResource = newValue [childPosition].Title;
        //imageView.SetImageResource(thumbIds[childPosition]);

        string imageurl = DataList[groupPosition].CategoryList[childPosition].FileName;

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imageurl))
        {
            if (FileExists(imageurl) == true)
            {
                var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(imageurl);
                imageView.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }
        }
        else
        { // clear the image
          // imageView.SetImageBitmap(null);
        }

        return imageView;
    }

    public override int GetChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        var results = DataList[groupPosition].CategoryList == null ? 0 : DataList[groupPosition].CategoryList.Count;
        return results;
    }

    public override int GroupCount
    {
        get
        {
            return DataList.Count;
        }
    }

    private void GetChildViewHelper(int groupPosition, out List<category> Value)
    {
        var results = DataList[groupPosition].CategoryList;
        Value = results;
    }

    private bool FileExists(string url)
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {

                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);

                return true;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {

                //throw any other exception - this should not occur
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


    private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {

                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);

                if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                }

            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {

                //throw any other exception - this should not occur
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }


    #region implemented abstract members of BaseExpandableListAdapter

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public override bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        var item = DataList[groupPosition].CategoryList[childPosition];
        //if (item.OnClickListener != null)
        //{
        //    item.OnClickListener.Invoke(item);
        //}
        //          return item.IsSelected = !item.IsSelected;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool HasStableIds
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This is my ImageAdapter.cs which is used to bind the Images to the GridView.

```
internal class ImageAdapter :BaseAdapter
{
    private readonly Context context;
    public int count = 0;
    public int Position = 0;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c,List<category>ChildList)
    {
        context = c;
        ChildData = ChildList;
        //Position = position;
    }

    protected List<category> ChildData { get; set; }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return ChildData.Count(); }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {

        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        count++;
        var item = ChildData[position];
        Bitmap bitmap1;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.LayoutParameters = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(85, 85);
            //imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
           // imageView.SetPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        else
        {
            imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }

        string imageurl = item.FileName;

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imageurl))
        {
            if(FileExists(imageurl)==true)
            {
                var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(imageurl);
                imageView.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }
        }
        else
        { // clear the image
           // imageView.SetImageBitmap(null);
        }



        //imageView.SetImageResource(thumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    private bool FileExists(string url)
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {

                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);

                return true;
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {

                //throw any other exception - this should not occur
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


    private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {

                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);

                if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                }

            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {

                //throw any other exception - this should not occur
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }


}
```

And the MainView axml files below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FBFCFC"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the ChildView axml in which I placed the GridView.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnWidth="60dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want these child images marked in red, to be displayed in tiles not one below other. [here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmSVG.png).

Comment: What is an image in Tile format?

Comment: I mean images displaying as tiles like in a gallery. Sorry that you couldn't get that :(